# getting specific images from page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am pretty new with `BeautifulSoup`. I am trying to print image links from http://www.bing.com/images?q=owl:

```
redditFile = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bing.com/images?q=owl")
redditHtml = redditFile.read()
redditFile.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(redditHtml)

productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'dg_u'})
for div in productDivs:
    print div.find('a')['t1']  #works fine
    print div.find('img')['src'] #This getting issue KeyError: 'src'
```

But this gives only title, not the image source
Is there anything wrong?

**Edit:**
I have edited my source, still could not get image url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing is using some techniques to block automated scrapers. I tried to print

```
div.find('img')
```

and found that they are sending source in attribute names src2, so following should work -

```
div.find('img')['src2']
```

This is working for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks! interesting too. how you get to know that they sending source named as `src2`

Comment: As I said I tried `print div.find('img')` which printed the whole html of the img tag.

Comment: thanks any heads on over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734483/get-div-attribute-val-and-div-text-body

Answer (score 1):

If you open up browser develop tools, you'll see that there is an additional async XHR request issued to the `http://www.bing.com/images/async` endpoint which contains the image search results.

Which leads to the 3 main options you have:

- simulate that XHR request in your code. You might want to use something more suitable for humans than `urllib2`; see [`requests` module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). This would be so called "low-level" approach, going down to the bare metal and web-site specific implementation which would make this option non-reliable, difficult, "heavy", error-prompt and fragile
- automate a real browser using [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org) - stay on the high-level. In other words, you don't care how the results are retrieved, what requests are made, what javascript needs to be executed. You just wait for search results to appear and extract them.
- use [Bing Search API](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingsearchapi) (this should probably be option #1)

Comment: thanks for answer, 1st(limit issue) and 3rd (working - but blocking issue) tried out. Not sure about 2nd. I appreciate if you share your knowledge and let me know which is more reliable and having long life