# get div attribute val and div text body

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is small code to get div attr value. All div name are same with same attr name.

```
redditFile = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bing.com/videos?q=owl")
redditHtml = redditFile.read()
redditFile.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(redditHtml)

productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'dg_u'})
for div in productDivs:
    print div.find('div', {"class":"vthumb"})['smturl']
    #print div.find("div", {"class":"tl text-body"}) This print none rather then div text
```

first print gives some urls(some times 4,6,8 etc) and then

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-cc950a8a84f7> in <module>()
     26 productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'dg_u'})
     27 for div in productDivs:
---> 28     print div.find('div', {"class":"vthumb"})['smturl']
     29     print div.find("div", {"class":"tl text-body"})

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    903         """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag,
    904         and throws an exception if it's not there."""
--> 905         return self.attrs[key]
    906 
    907     def __iter__(self):

KeyError: 'smturl'
```

as all div name are same with same `smturl` attr name, why it gives `KeyError` any help?

Comment: Not all your `div` have `smturl` attibute. One way to find out is: `for div in productDivs: if 'smturl' not in div.find('div', {"class":"vthumb"}).attrs: print(div)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all divs have `smturl` attribute, so you need to add the attribute to `find` call. Also not all elements in `productDivs` contain divs you are looking for, hence I've added test if `find` returns None.

```
In [27]: for div in productDivs:
  ....:     if div.find('div', {"class":"vthumb", 'smturl': True}) is not None:
  ....:         print div.find('div', {"class":"vthumb", 'smturl': True})['smturl']
  ....:
http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB.9hfZ6cCDfUWbpw&pid=2.1
http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB1.n%2b12M8SoyFcsag&pid=2.1
http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB.ev1wnIiszGjhUg&pid=2.1
http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB.hDLa5PO07Chclw&pid=2.1
http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB.xDT9H25QFJ2jBw&pid=2.1
http://ts3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB.BULQolkxkaZ0uw&pid=2.1
http://ts3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB.xp3c0DyKrfmB7Q&pid=2.1
http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB.MxP9fUyaJCRyhw&pid=2.1
http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB2.CWjPPKiJQc4z6w&pid=2.1
http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB1.ZVKhvML3%2bPzM1w&pid=2.1
http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB.SLn%2b0NwKeUdZXw&pid=2.1
http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB.4HJqrT9pBevGlg&pid=2.1
http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB2.HgWYR9sjPw6JlQ&pid=2.1
http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB.RyBXWQ9sH9wThw&pid=2.1
http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB2.Vf21EgXRXMcdfg&pid=2.1
http://ts3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB2.BIb6qwbHniC1vw&pid=2.1
http://ts3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OMB1.H9bwRYncKU380A&pid=2.1
http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OM1.mBXeu55OD4VimQ&pid=2.1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can you please tell me why `print div.find("div", {"class":"tl text-body"})` does not print div content?

Comment: @nlper because there are no such divs on the page.  I've used Chrome developer tools to locate them and got nothing `$x("//div[contains(@class, 'text-body')]");   []`

Comment: `<div class="tl fade" style="width:198px">Husband Fools Wife - Hindi <strong>Jokes</strong> 9</div>` this is the div and I am trying to get `Husband Fools Wife - Hindi ` using `text-body`

Comment: @nlper why did you add `text-body` in your initial `find` call then?

Comment: @nlper use `print div.find("div", {"class":"tl fade"})` instead

Comment: thanks again, but this prints entire div `<div class="tl fade" style="width:175px">True Facts About The <strong>Owl</strong></div>` rather I want body text of the div only i.e. `True Facts About The Owl` , so I was tryign it with `text-body`

Comment: okay got it `print div.find("div", {"class":"tl fade"}).text`